# Big execution time difference between java Lambda vs Anonymous class

Tags: java, performance, lambda, closures, java-8

I was curious about performance of creation of java8 lambda instances against the same anonymous class. (Measurement performed on win32 java build 1.8.0-ea-b106). I've created very simple example and measured if java propose some optimization of `new` operator while create lambda expression:

```
static final int MEASURES = 1000000;
static interface ICallback{
    void payload(int[] a);
}
/**
* force creation of anonymous class many times
*/
static void measureAnonymousClass(){
    final int arr[] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < MEASURES; ++i){
        ICallback clb = new ICallback() {
            @Override
            public void payload(int[] a) {
                a[0]++;
            }
        };
        clb.payload(arr);
    }
}
/**
* force creation of lambda many times 
*/
static void measureLambda(){ 
    final int arr[] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i < MEASURES; ++i){
        ICallback clb = (a2) -> {
            a2[0]++;
        };
        clb.payload(arr);
    }
}
```

(Full code can be taken there: http://codepad.org/Iw0mkXhD) The result is rather predictable - lambda wins 2 times.

But really little shift to make [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) shows very bad time for lambda. Anonymous class wins 10 times! 
So now anonymous class looks like:

```
ICallback clb = new ICallback() {
        @Override
        public void payload() {
            arr[0]++;
        }
    };
```

And lambda does as follow:

```
ICallback clb = () -> {
            arr[0]++;
        };
```

(Full code can be taken there: http://codepad.org/XYd9Umty )
Can anybody explain me why exists so big (bad) difference in handling of closure?

Comment: That's a quite naïve approach to microbenchmarking. At the very least use `System.nanoTime` and introduce throwaway executions to warm up the JVM. Several `System.gc()` calls between executions would alse be a good idea. Ideally, do this with Google Caliper or Oracle jmh.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - actually I've foreseen this note, that is why I performed 2 measurements when `measureLambda` run first and when `measureLambda` runs after `measureAnonymousClass` - without any impact at all! And nanoTime can show difference in precise measurement, but not when I'm talking about 10 times

Comment: You mean 10 seconds? Also, it would have helped if you included the note about running in both orders in your question text.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik :) oh no, for my CPU: for first case (where lambda wins) 7ms vs 14ms, for second case (with closure where lambda lose) 160ms vs 20ms. The order change doesn't affect measured time.

Comment: The accuracy of `currentTimeMillis` is often at the level of a tenth of a second (platform-dependent). The accuracy of `nanoTime` is typically on the level of a microsecond. Also, just reordering executions doesn't prove anything: each code path must be warmed up on its own. Warm-up executions is the way to do it and garbage collection **must** be controlled for.

Comment: You create a new object in every iteration, that's a huge number of objects. You do little besides that (just call a method which does one trivial operation). GC time could even dominate the overall time spent.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik -  there is no issue with GC - because both cases DO THE SAME NUMBER OF ALLOCATIONS. First program doesn't use closure second program use it. Did you ever try to understand what both programs do? I'm absolutelly agree that lot of time is spent by GC but the same time spent in both programs! So this is permanent deviation and no difference if I measure this with warm-up or with nano- measurement. Just to proof my position I've placed recommend by you Google Caliper and warm-up! YOU COMMENTS ARE IRRELEVANT - because relative number the same x2 and x10.

Comment: Did you actually measure the GC overhead, or are you just guessing? Waving hands and shouting that GC times are the same with absolutely no solid evidence is not the way to enlightenment. Allocations are measured in bytes, not in allocation count. Do you at least have a solid proof that in both cases the exact same number of bytes is allocated?

Comment: "I've placed recommend by you Google Caliper and warm-up!" --- I don't understand this sentence.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the point of my comments so far: it is falsifying a number of standard hypotheses about the common sources of error while benchmarking on the JVM. Only when you have those solidly cleared can you enter a serious discussion of the results.

Comment: Note that, besides the fact that this benchmark is far away from the intended use case, just specifying the `-server` option at JVM start will make the recorded overhead go away entirely.

Comment: @Holger - just tried your recommendation and get exact same result as for regular JRE. Closure in lambda *slower* than closure for anonymous class near the 10 times.

Answer (score 30):

#### UPDATE

A few comments wondering if my benchmark at the bottom was flawed - after introducing a lot of randomness (to prevent the JIT from optimising too much stuff), I still get similar results so I tend to think it is ok.

In the meantime, I have come across [this presentation](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/7/7b/Goetz-jvmls-lambda.pdf) by the lambda implementation team. Page 16 shows some performance figures: inner classes and closures have similar performance / non-capturing lambda are up to 5x times faster.

And @StuartMarks posted this [JVMLS 2013 talk from Sergey Kuksenko on lambda performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UX8ChrIMrM). The bottom line is that post JIT compilation, lambdas and anonymous classes perform similarly on current Hostpot JVM implementations.

---

#### YOUR BENCHMARK

I have also run your test, as you posted it. The problem is that it runs for as little as 20 ms for the first method and 2 ms for the second. Although that is a 10:1 ratio, it is in no way representative because the measurement time is way too small.

I have then taken modified your test to allow for more JIT warmup and I get similar results as with jmh (i.e. no difference between anonymous class and lambda).

```
public class Main {

    static interface ICallback {
        void payload();
    }
    static void measureAnonymousClass() {
        final int arr[] = {0};
        ICallback clb = new ICallback() {
            @Override
            public void payload() {
                arr[0]++;
            }
        };
        clb.payload();
    }
    static void measureLambda() {
        final int arr[] = {0};
        ICallback clb = () -> {
            arr[0]++;
        };
        clb.payload();
    }
    static void runTimed(String message, Runnable act) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            act.run();
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(message + ":" + (end - start));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runTimed("as lambdas", Main::measureLambda);
        runTimed("anonymous class", Main::measureAnonymousClass);
        runTimed("as lambdas", Main::measureLambda);
        runTimed("anonymous class", Main::measureAnonymousClass);
        runTimed("as lambdas", Main::measureLambda);
        runTimed("anonymous class", Main::measureAnonymousClass);
        runTimed("as lambdas", Main::measureLambda);
        runTimed("anonymous class", Main::measureAnonymousClass);
    }
}
```

The last run takes about 28 seconds for both methods.

---

#### JMH MICRO BENCHMARK

I have run [the same test with jmh](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/09e3902b1396f44555b59741cd243fe97888f1cd/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/SO19001241_Closures.java) and the bottom line is that the four methods take as much time as the equivalent:

```
void baseline() {
    arr[0]++;
}
```

In other words, the JIT inlines both the anonymous class and the lambda and they take exactly the same time.

Results summary:

```
Benchmark                Mean    Mean error    Units
empty_method             1.104        0.043  nsec/op
baseline                 2.105        0.038  nsec/op
anonymousWithArgs        2.107        0.028  nsec/op
anonymousWithoutArgs     2.120        0.044  nsec/op
lambdaWithArgs           2.116        0.027  nsec/op
lambdaWithoutArgs        2.103        0.017  nsec/op
```

Comment: Really thank you for you checking. I've just re-run your code on my comp and get absolutely same number from my example above:
...
lambdaWithArgs...7.121
lambdaWithoutArgs....176.568,

So what can affect my comp?

Comment: @Dewfy Not sure to be honest - it can be many things. You should start by applying proper warmup before starting your measurement, monitoring GC and compilation to make sure you are measuring compiled code and checking the time spent in GC.

Comment: I've just started your code by: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.assylias.performance.RunTest"` - is it *proper warmup*?

Comment: @Dewfy do you get a long output with Warmup iterations and normal iterations as well as a table similar to the results in my answer (i.e. jmh's output)? If you do then yes - and I need to rerun my test if you don't get the same results!

Comment: The first thing I'd check here is runtime when no allocation is involved. I'd also do some 1000 iterations inside the test method to eliminate any overhead of method invocation.

Comment: BTW I start the benchmark simply with `java -jar target/microbenchmarks.jar '.*' -wi <warmup_iterations> -i <main_iterations>`. I don't get a long output for warmup, just a short note "Warmup iteration 1" etc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I run with roughly the same options (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/assylias/performance/src/09e3902b1396f44555b59741cd243fe97888f1cd/src/main/java/com/assylias/performance/RunTest.java?at=master))

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik empty method takes 1.1ns, method that just does the addition and returns the value takes 2.1ns (which sounds reasonable for a variable read + addition + variable write) and the anonymous/lmabda versions take 2.1ns too. I might have messed up somewhere...

Comment: That result would imply that the JIT completely eliminated the allocation of the actual lambda/anonymous class instances. However, if OP is having different results, then I'd proceed as described: separate out the allocation from invocation, see if the discrepancy is still there.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Mmmmm.... Changed a few things and it looks like the JIT killed my test.... Will have to try again. On the other hand the result made sense (the operation is only a few cycles and is a good candidate for inlining)...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Reran the whole thing with a good dose of randomness - each method takes a lot longer - but they still all take the same time... I think my results are ok - but feel free to share yours if you have time to give it a try.

Comment: I don't have a JDK 8 set up... otherwise I'd not be spending time just talking :) The key here could be escape analysis which may eliminate dynamic allocation. Do you say that with randomness there is still no difference between direct method call (`baseline`) and indirect calls on lambda/anonymous instances? Maybe the randomness doesn't impede escape analysis. The way to break it is by putting the instance into an ArrayList or something similar.

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure that OP's large discrepancy is due to one code path having the advantage of EA and the other going through the full dynamic allocation. I don't see anything else which would explain a factor of 10 and more.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If the code was really the one linked in the question, it runs in less than 20 ms on my machine, so result can't be stable or relevant. Simply repeating the test within the same JVM session helps and allowing for enough warmup gets similar results as what I got initially.

Comment: As you can see, I was trying to explain the same to OP 8 hours ago :) There's still an off chance that on his machine there may be discrepancies, but it will once again amount to nothing more than that very specific code resulting in EA working for one and not the other. You change any tiny little thing and the effect is gone. So my conclusion is that nothing really big will be learned here. Anyway, what's the difference at the bytecode level between the anon class and the lambda? They both compile into the same, or nearly the same class, don't they?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Nop - anonymous class uses invokespecial + an inner class vs. lambda uses invokedynamic and does not create a new inner class.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea it used dynamic invocation! That opens the possibility of lower performance for the dispatch itself.

Comment: Thanks for writing down your performance investigations. +1. The original (mostly prototype) JDK 8 implementation of lambda was exactly an anonymous inner class, to get something working early so that we could explore language and library evolution. This seems to have spawned a myth that lambdas are nothing more than anonymous inner classes. More recently the implementation has been optimized so that lambda is almost always faster than the "equivalent" anonymous inner class.

Comment: Also, there are two great JVM Language Summit talks from the performance guys. First, Alexey Shipilev (author of jmh) talks about benchmarking and its many pitfalls. (This was voted best talk at JVMLS this year.) Second, Sergey Kuksenko talks about what he's been doing to optimize lambda performance.

[1] http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/2630310904001

[2] http://medianetwork.oracle.com/video/player/2623576348001

Comment: @StuartMarks Let me join in with Brian Goetz and the slides from his [talk on implementing the lambda](http://wiki.jvmlangsummit.com/images/7/7b/Goetz-jvmls-lambda.pdf) in Java.

Comment: @StuartMarks It would be interesting to know why lamnndas are in fact not just (important) syntactic sugar for anonymous inner classes.  They sure look like that from the spec, which is a good thing IMHO.  If you have figured out a way to improve the performance of lambdas, then surely that would also apply to anonymous classes, or are they no longer cool?  I would expect that the final code produced by the JIT would be almost exactly the same for both, but that you had to work a lot, lot harder to get that to happen for Dynamic Invoke.

Comment: @StuartMarks Your links to those Shipilev talks appear to now be broken.

Comment: JVMLS 2013 talk: Aleksey Shipilev, "JVM Benchmarking" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x3Vlze1mUj4

Comment: JVMLS 2013 talk: Sergey Kuksenko, "Lambda Performance" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UX8ChrIMrM

Comment: @Tuntable Links updated. Thanks for mentioning this.