# How Java 8 Lambdas compare to plain method calls when Collections are not involved?

Tags: java, performance, lambda

In Java 8, what's the performance impact of choosing the use of functional interfaces over vanilla method calls?

Suppose I have to call a method several times, using repeated values for 3 of its 5 arguments:

```
boolean isGood = getIsGood();
boolean isOk = getIsOk();
int year = getYear();

processCitiesByYear("Germany", "Berlin", isGood, isOk, year);
processCitiesByYear("USA", "New York City", isGood, isOk, year);
processCitiesByYear("Italy", "Rome", isGood, isOk, year);
processCitiesByYear("Japan","Tokyo", isGood, isOk, year);
processCitiesByYear("Canada","Montreal", isGood, isOk, year);
processCitiesByYear("Spain","Madrid", isGood, isOk, year);
```

I can create a `java.util.function.BiConsumer` to avoid the "`isGood, isOk, year`" repetition, and make the code more readable (imho):

```java
boolean isGood = getIsGood();
boolean isOk = getIsOk();
int year = getYear();

BiConsumer<String, String> processGoodAndOkInYear= 
    (country, city) -> {
        processCitiesByYear(country, city, isGood, isOk, year);
    };

processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("Germany", "Berlin");
processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("USA", "New York City");
processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("Italy", "Rome");
processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("Japan","Tokyo");
processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("Canada","Montreal");
processGoodAndOkInYear.accept("Spain","Madrid");
```

Am I heavily sacrificing performance with this "design pattern"? Or does the JVM magically [turns my `processGoodAndOkInYear` into compiled code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) and it turns out to be actually more efficient than the 5 arguments calls?

Comment: What results did you get when you profiled it yourself?

Comment: Good question. I think the answer is best summarized in a Dutch proverb: "meten is weten". Basically: to be sure, measure it!

Comment: At first I thought about making measurements, but then I noticed things could vary a lot with number of arguments (repeated and not), number of methods calls, the combination of functional interfaces (say a BiFunction<String, Function<String,Boolean>, Predicate<Integer>>)... I believe knowledge about the inner workings can better answer my doubts about the overall "design patter".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think the Lambda could be faster than method calls, but it should be very close. You can take a look at the following links :

- Oracle benchmark on Lambdas : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jvmls2013kuksen-2014088.pdf
- Stackoverflow user's benchmark : [Big execution time difference between java Lambda vs Anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001241/big-execution-time-difference-between-java-lambda-vs-anonymous-class)

Now, I wouldn't use Lambda here, as a simple wrapper method will do :

```
private void processGoodAndOkin2001(String country, String city) {
    processCitiesByYear(country, city, true, true, 2001);
}
```

Perfs will be similar this way.

Comment: The wrapper method approach is of course better when we know the repeated arguments values at compile time, as in my example code. A better example would use variable as the values passed repeatedly. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Well, the method name implies the repeated parameters value in this case. But you're right on the matter. In this case, you can alway call the getGood() and getOK() methods within the wrapper method.

Comment: No I can't, unless I assume getGood() and getOk() has no side effects. Suppose, for instance, that getGood() interactively asks the user to choose 'yes' or 'no'.

Comment: I don't think that would matter anyway. Your application will then just hang there, waiting for the user input. Even so, how would Lambdas address that better (still new to Lambdas, so I might not get something) ?

Comment: The point is that, in the above example, I wouldn't want to repeatedly ask the user "Are those cities good?", "Are they ok?" and "Which year?". Remember its supposed to use the same values at every call.

Comment: Ok I understand you point. Then just create boolean variables from those methods outside the method scope. But again, I don't see the benefit of using Lambdas for this purpose (which is not a criticism, but only a point of view).

Comment: Using variable outside of the method would work. But here comes my question: Does running accept() in a n-parameter faster than running a n+1-parameter method (all other things equal)? Does the lambda take advantage of knowing the values beforehand?

Comment: I think old-fashioned way will have slightly better performances, because params are either values (for primitives) or references (for complex types like String). In Lambda it will be exactly the same. So as method call seems slightly faster than Lambda one, this explains my point of view