# Java extend Generic Type Parameter

Tags: java, c++, templates, generics

I'm coming from C++ and I'm trying to inherit the Generic parameter type in Java. Basically, I'm trying to emulate the below C++ pattern:

In C++, I can do:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
        Node* next;
};


class BaseVisitor
{
    public:
        BaseVisitor(Node* ptr)
        {
            std::cout<<ptr<<"\n\n";
            delete ptr;
        }
        ~BaseVisitor() {};

    protected:
        virtual Node* Generate() = 0;
};


class DynamicVisitor : public BaseVisitor
{
    public:
        DynamicVisitor(Node* ptr) : BaseVisitor(ptr) {}

    protected:
        virtual Node* Generate()
        {
            std::cout<<"Dynamic Visitor\n";
            return new Node();
        }
};

class StaticVisitor : public BaseVisitor
{
    public:
        StaticVisitor(Node* ptr) : BaseVisitor(ptr) {}

    protected:
        virtual Node* Generate()
        {
            std::cout<<"Static Visitor\n";
            return NULL;
        }
};



template<typename T>
class TestVisitor : public T  //THIS is where the magic happens..
{
    public:
        TestVisitor() : T(this->Generate()) {} //allows me to call "Generate".
};

int main()
{
    TestVisitor<DynamicVisitor> foo = TestVisitor<DynamicVisitor>();
    TestVisitor<StaticVisitor> bar = TestVisitor<StaticVisitor>();
}
```

Output:

```
Dynamic Visitor
0x605ed0

Static Visitor
NULL
```

How can I do the same thing in Java? I tried:

```
public class Node {
    Node next;
}

public abstract class BaseVisitor {
    public BaseVisitor(Node n) {System.out.println(n);}

    protected abstract Node generate();
}

public class DynamicVisitor extends BaseVisitor {
    public DynamicVisitor(Node n) {
        super(n);
    }

    @Override
    protected Node generate() {
        return new Node();
    }
}

public class StaticVisitor extends BaseVisitor {

    public StaticVisitor(Node n) {
        super(n);
    }

    @Override
    protected Node generate() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class TestVisitor<T extends BaseVisitor> extends T { //error.. Cannot extend "T".. No magic happens..
    public TestVisitor() {
        super(this.generate()); //cannot call generate()..
    }
}
```

1. What is this pattern called? I call it "Base Factory" pattern but I'm not sure the real name for it so I wasn't sure what to search for..
2. How can I do the same thing as in C++, in Java? Is there "any way" to do the same pattern in Java?

Comment: That's where C++ zings while java zangs. In C++ templates are basically fancy preprocessor macros, that lead to different runtime objects being generated. In java, there is only one version of a templatized class at runtime (with its type parameter erased). That forbids you from doing things like the above. You can however come up with solutions using anonymous classes or java 8 lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, can't do this in java, sorry. The closest is, probably, a "delegate pattern":

```
public interface NodeGenerator {  Node generate(); }
public class StaticGenerator implements NodeGenerator { 
    public Node generate() { return null; }
}
public class DynamicGenerator implements NodeGenerator {
    public Node generate() { return new Node(); }
}

public class TestVisitor extends BaseVisitor {
     public TestVisitor(NodeGenerator g) { super(g.generate()); }
}
```

In java 8, you can make this look nicer (but possibly less efficient), without the extra interfaces and classes:

```
public class TestVisitor extends BaseVisitor {
    public TestVisitor(Supplier<Node> g) { super(g.get()); }
}

// ... and then you can do things like

TestVisitor staticVisitor = new TestVisitor(() -> null);
TestVisitor dynamicVisitor = new TestVisitor(() -> new Node());
```

Comment: Why do you suggest it's _possibly less efficient_?

Comment: Well, I said "possibly", because I am not sure about how exactly this is implemented. What I have in mind is something like this: `NodeGenerator ng = new StaticNodeGenerator(); for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { new TestVisitor(ng); }` vs. `for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) { new TestVisitor(() -> null); }`. It seems to me, that the latter approach is going to allocate 10000 more objects (that can be avoided), and, *possibly*,  generate 10000 extra anonymous classes (that would be unavoidable).

Comment: You could replace the first example with anonymous classes and obtain code that's almost as concise as the java 8 version!

Comment: @GiovanniBotta ~50 extra characters (3 lines) per call ... :-/

Comment: The lambda version doesn't capture anything, so it doesn't need to allocate extra objects.  Those supplier calls will just be executed as method invocations by the JVM.

Comment: @GregKopff no, I am pretty sure, that `foo(() -> null)` is equivalent to `foo(new Supplier<Node> { public Node generate()  { return null; } })`: a new anonymous class is generated, a new instance of that class is allocated and initialized, and then passed to the method call as a parameter.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Supplier<Object> s1 = Object::new;
 System.out.println(s1.hashCode()); }` only allocates one `Supplier` instance.

Comment: @Dima AFAIK that is not true. Two years ago at JavaOne Brian Goetz said that implementing lambdas using anonymous classes would have been a shortcut and they wanted to do it right. So I assume there is some JVM magic that shortcuts the creation of a new object in cases like this. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001241/big-execution-time-difference-between-java-lambda-vs-anonymous-class).